# Cast List<Son> to List<Father>

Tags: java, list, collections, casting

I have a simple POJO named "Father" and another one named "Son" which extends "Father", the simplest class inheritance example.

Now I have a `List<Son>` and I need to cast it to a `List<Father>`.

How can I do?

**EDIT**

Sorry for the bad naming, I didn't explain myself. **Person** and **Employee** would have been a better example. Or **Product** and **Computer**, too.

Comment: Why would you want to cast "down"? A `Son` is a `Father`, so it can do anything a `Father` can do...

Comment: [You can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit) => you will need to copy the content.

Comment: There is a logical flaw here. Not every `Son` is a `Father`. However it can be true in a parallel universe.

Comment: A `Son` is a `Father`? A son **has-a** father. The real world example cries for composition instead of inheritance!

Comment: Inheritance in object oriented programming has a completely different meaning than in biology. In OO, inheritance means **specialization**: a subclass *is a specialized version of* a superclass. Using names such as `Father` and `Son` for the classes confuses it with the biological meaning of inheritance.

Comment: @Andreas_D obviously... the right example would be "Person" and "SalesPerson"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 suggestions:

Have an Interface, say `Person`, that `Father` (and thus `Son`) implements. Use `List<Person>` for both.

Create a `new List<Father>` with the collection Constructor, e.g. `List<Father> fathers = new ArrayList<Father>(sons);`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a cast here* as commented above. You could write a small helper method to do the conversion (i.e.the copy):

```
private static List<Father> getListFather(List<? extends Father> list) {
    return new ArrayList<> (list);
}
```

<sub>* Actually you can - cf the other answer: `List<Father> listFather = (List<Father>) (List<? extends Father>) listSons;`</sub>

Comment: This code misses `<A>` from the method signature, and still needs to be called with a generic hint, but it's the only typesafe way I know.

Comment: @Slanec What do you mean "This code misses <A> from the method signature" ? (I've changed A into Father but the rest is the same)

Comment: With `Father` it works well. I thought your `A` was a generic type for the method to work with all the possible types. And in that case, it would need to be `private static <A> List<A> getList(List<? extends A> list)` and also would need a generic hint when called.

Answer (score 3):

Assume for a moment you could do that with a cast, it would lead to the following problem:

```
List<Son> ls = ...;
List<Father> lf = (List<Son>) ls;
lf.add(new Father());
```

Both `ls` and `lf` point to the same instance so you have just added a `Father` object into a list of Sons.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
static class Father {};
static class Son extends Father{};

public void test() {
  List<Son> sons = new ArrayList<>();
  // Not allowed.
  //List<Father> sons2 = (List<Father>)sons;
  // Two step.
  List<? extends Father> sons3 = sons;
  List<Father> sons4 = (List<Father>)sons3;
  // Direct.
  List<Father> sons5 = (List<Father>)((List<? extends Father>)sons);
}
```

Comment: Also, `List<Father> fathers = (List<Father>)(List<? super Son>)sons;`. But beware, you're avoiding the Java type safety which could end up backfiring easily!

Comment: Not sure I would recommended it but nice ;-)